# How to verify if kafka compression is working

Tags: apache-kafka, compression

I am trying snappy compression on my producer. Here's my setup

Kafka - 2.0.0
Spring-Kafka - 2.1.2

Here's my producer config

compressed producer

```
configProps.put( ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            bootstrapServer);
    configProps.put(
            ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(
            ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 10);
```

config of un-compressed producer

```
configProps.put(
            ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
            bootstrapServer);
    configProps.put(
            ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(
            ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            StringSerializer.class);
```

My payload is almost 1mb worth of string. After sending 1000 compressed and 1000 uncompressed such messages this is the result

```
[shantanu@oc0148610736 uncompressed-string-test-0]$ du -hsc /data/compressed-string-test-0/*
8.0K    /data/compressed-string-test-0/00000000000000000000.index
990M    /data/compressed-string-test-0/00000000000000000000.log
12K /data/compressed-string-test-0/00000000000000000000.timeindex
4.0K    /data/compressed-string-test-0/leader-epoch-checkpoint
990M    total
[shantanu@oc0148610736 uncompressed-string-test-0]$ du -shc /data/uncompressed-string-test-0/*
8.0K    /data/uncompressed-string-test-0/00000000000000000000.index
992M    /data/uncompressed-string-test-0/00000000000000000000.log
12K /data/uncompressed-string-test-0/00000000000000000000.timeindex
4.0K    /data/uncompressed-string-test-0/leader-epoch-checkpoint
992M    total
```

Here we can see difference is merely 2MB. Is compression even working? I used dump-log-segment tool

```
[shantanu@oc0148610736 kafka_2.11-2.0.0]$ sh bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.DumpLogSegments --files /data/compressed-string-test-0/00000000000000000000.log --print-data-log | head | grep compresscodec
offset: 0 position: 0 CreateTime: 1620744081357 isvalid: true keysize: -1 valuesize: 1039999 magic: 2 compresscodec: SNAPPY producerId: -1 producerEpoch: -1 sequence: -1 isTransactional: false headerKeys: [] payload: klxhbpyxmcazvhekqnltuenwhsewjjfmctcqyrppellyfqglfnvhqctlfplslhpuulknsncbgzzndizwmlnelotcbniyprdgihdazwn
```

I can see SNAPPY is mentioned as compression codec. But difference between compressed and uncompressed disk size is negligible.

Is compression really working here? Please help

Comment: Did you tried to execute kafka-log-dirs for both compressed and un-compressed topics?

`kafka-log-dirs --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --topic-list topic`